# Summing up trues in different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have checks for multiple sheets in excel (e.g. B3=D3 and it will say true/false). So I have a true/false in say 10 different sheets, all in e.g. cell B2.

Is there a formula I can create on my summary page to highlight to me if any of the checks are FALSE? (i.e. if any 1 of my 10 sheets says false, this formula will say false too)

Answer (score 1):

Just this will do:

```
=AND(Sheet1:Sheet10!B2)
```

Just change *Sheet1* to your first check sheet and *Sheet10* to the last one, ensure you only have checking sheets inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply same logic in you summary page. for example enter this formula `=Sheet2!B2=Sheet3!B2=Sheet4!B2=Sheet5!B2` in summary page (adjust it to fit all sheets). if any B2 value is False, your summary value will also be false...